# Configuring prefix 'www' in iis for a domain?

Tags: windows, web, dns, server

I deleted some records from the DNS configuration Manager in `Windows Server 2012 Datacenter`. I am in a remote connection and trying to configure the right DNS record to get the prefix `www`.domain.com.

I have tried a CNAME record `www` to domain.com. However, it didn't work.

Comment: you should post this into serverfault, stackoverflow is more about code than servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it correctly in A-records.

in foward lookup zones, domainname.com folder set:

- name = www
- type = Host(A)
- data = {server ip}

And maybe you need to wait a bit for dns propagation (or set as dns your dns server to test it faster on a client)

Comment: I was trying... I probably need to restart the entire server, and wait for the dns to be found

Comment: no need restart the server, if you want to restart something do only a dns restart, but it is not needed, try to set a client with dns your server ip, you will be able to test it faster

Comment: I restarted my server. And it works :D thank you really much for the support :)